# I can't type in the first window

Tags: 16.04, msi, typing-break

I bought a MSI laptop recently and I struggled to install Ubuntu. Now I have it installed and I have a weird issue. When I open, for example, a Terminal, I can't type anything. But if I open a new one when the other is open I can. It's not just happening with Terminal, it happens with everything.

I installed Ubuntu with the grub-flag acpi=off

Does anyone know why is this happening?

Cheers!